# How to Call usercontrol in Windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I am working with windowsForm in vb.Net.
I have one main form(frmMaster) that has buttons on the left side and one panel(PanelDetail) control on the right side.
I have two user controls, let say uc1 and uc2.
When I clicked the button from main form, it opens the uc1 in the panel properly through below code.

```
PanelDetail.Controls.Add(uc1)
uc1.Show()
```

There is a button control on uc1 and i wants to open uc2, when user clicks on the button from uc1.
So i have to add the uc2 to the PanelDetail and hide or remove the uc1. To do this, i have created the public method in the frmMaster

```
 Public Sub DisplayControl(ControlName As UserControl)
    PanelDetail.Controls.Clear()
    PanelDetail.Controls.Add(ControlName)
    ControlName.Show()
 End Sub
```

and call this method from the button click event of the uc1 to call uc2

```
 frmMaster.DisplayControl(frmMaster.vuc2)
```

uc2 is already declared as shared in the main form as

```
Public Shared vuc2 As New CtrlLeavesList
```

So when i click the button from uc1, it clears the uc1 from panel, but it does not load the uc2.

can anyone suggest me the right way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: While it is legal to call `formName.PublicMethod` it does not mean your are getting the form instance. You could use an event on the UC and the form subscribes to, when the event fires you have the code run in the event handler to remove and add a different control to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

As OneFineDay said, you can declare an event in uc1.

```
Public Event RemoveButtonClicked()
```

Then in the event handler for the actual button on the user control (uc1), you raise the event.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent RemoveButtonClicked()
End Sub
```

Then in the main form, you would declare an instance of the uc1, and register a handle for the event.

```
Public WithEvents uc1 As New CtrlLeavesList

Public Sub uc1_RemoveButtonClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles uc1.RemoveButtonClicked
    DisplayControl(uc2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and your time.

Comment: I have tried to follow the steps but could not understand the flow. why i need to declare the event in uc2. i cannot raise the event in uc1 button, its giving syntax error and further the same issue with event register on the main form. can you please send the correct syntax. Thanks for your effort

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry, you are correct. I have made the corrections. Let me know if you still can't get it working.

Comment: I am getting this error in the main form in handle clause of uc1_RemoveButtonClicked "handles clause requires a withevents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types".

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using below code.
You need to define the public event as below in uc1

```
Public Event RemoveButtonClicked As EventHandler
```

and then raise the event in button click of the uc1

```
 Private Sub btnApplyLeave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnApplyLeave.Click

    RaiseEvent RemoveButtonClicked(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Then in the main form, you would declare an instance of the uc1, and register a handle for the event.

```
Public Shared uc1 As New CtrlLeavesList
Public Shared uc2 As New CtrlApplyforLeave
```

Then most important you need to add the handler on the form load of the main form

```
 AddHandler vCtrlLeavesList.RemoveButtonClicked, AddressOf vCtrlLeavesList_RemoveButtonClicked
```

and then register the event

```
 Public Sub vCtrlLeavesList_RemoveButtonClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   PanelDetail.Controls.Add(uc2)
uc2.Show()

End Sub
```

The above example is working perfectly for me.